# Difference between Read, Restricted Read and View permissions

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions

When I started reading about permissions, I came through these three different permissions levels.

I got a bit of idea for what is `Read Permission`, but I cannot see the difference between the `Restricted Read` and `View Permission`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know this you should better understand about the SharePoint permissions. The below will give a quick idea about your query.

Read, View Only, Restricted read - *These are all SharePoint Permission Levels*

**So what is permission level?** Permission level is a collection of certain Base permissions. If you have Full control access in the site you may get it via,

> Site Settings > Site Permissions > Permission Levels (in ribbon)

**So what is base permission?** It is the built-in permissions provided by SharePoint. The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx) link gives more information about base permission. You may get it via,

> Site Settings > Site Permissions > Permission Levels (in ribbon) >
>   Click on required permission level

So coming to your query, the `Base permissions` is the key factor that makes the difference between `Restriceted read` and `View` permission. Given below the base permissions of `View` and `Restricted read`

**Restricted Read**

*List Permissions*

- View Items  -  View items in lists and documents in document
  libraries.
- Open Items  -  View the source of documents with server-side file
  handlers.

*Site Permissions*

- View Pages  -  View pages in a Web site.
- Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to
  access items inside that container.

**View Only**

*List Permissions*

- View Items  -  View items in lists and documents in document
  libraries.
- Open Items  -  View the source of documents with server-side file
  handlers.
- View Versions  -  View past versions of a list item or document.
- Create Alerts  -  Create alerts.
- View Application Pages  -  View forms, views, and application pages.
  Enumerate lists.

*Site Permissions*

- Use Self-Service Site Creation  -  Create a Web site using
  Self-Service Site Creation.
- View Pages  -  View pages in a Web site.
- Browse User Information  -  View information about users of the Web
  site.
- Use Remote Interfaces  -  Use SOAP, Web DAV, the Client Object Model
  or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site.
- Use Client Integration Features  -  Use features which launch client
  applications. Without this permission, users will have to work on
  documents locally and upload their changes.
- Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to
  access items inside that container.

Hope it clarifies your query.